# TeXstudio Macro to change text into \index{text}

Tags: macros, texstudio, makeindex

I am currently in the process of writing a book, and it's only after I've written almost 200 pages that I realized I didn't take into consideration the index. I'm using the package imadeidx which works great, but having written all my definitions, I now need to go back and append \index{} next to all of them. Is there a way to define a macro that immediately puts my selection into \index{}? For instance, I select the word "number" with my mouse and then do Ctrl+Shift+9 (say) and it changes the selection into \index{number}. I'm not sure where to find documentation on this kind of macro so even just a nod in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a user macro:

```
%SCRIPT
cursor.replaceSelectedText("\\index{" + cursor.selectedText() + "}")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect!

Comment: @Saegusa You're welcome!